# Tkinter Checkbutton created from a SQLite database using a For Loop always returns false

Tags: python, sqlite, for-loop, tkinter, variable-assignment

sort of a beginner  at python programming but ive run into a roadblock and need a little assistance. i have a data base of two items, which are basically just a name for a crypto, and a id that needs to be passed later. i'm trying to use the for loop to create checkbuttons that take the id as the `onvalue` so that i can get them from the variable and pass them later. I'm trying to create these checkbuttons inside of a labelframe that's attached to a different window, but I'm calling Tk and running mainloop and everything is set up properly, its just one little issue ill explain down below

here's whats contained in the coinlist db database and `fetchedcoins` variable:

```
[('Bitcoin', 'bitcoin', 1), ('Ethereum', 'ethereum', 2)]
```

so when i iterate through the database for the first item, it sets the id variable to the on value properly, but when it hits the second item, it replaces the previous coinid data in the checkbutton `var` variable with the coinid of the new coin, and as a result when i activate the `pasteids` function and get the checkbutton variable to use in a label, it only returns the onvalue for the checkbutton of the last item of the list, since that was the database item that was last loaded into the variable. even if the last item is deselected and the other is selected, the other items on value returns false.  im wondering if theres a way for me to create different variables for each item of the loop, so that the state  variable `var` doesnt only reflect the state of the last button that was created. any tips or workarounds help are greatly appreciated

```
def selectcoins():
    selectframe = LabelFrame(avreadermain, text='Select Coins')
    selectframe.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=20,pady=15,sticky=W+E)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('coinlist.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT *, oid FROM coins')
    fetchedcoins = cursor.fetchall()

    for coins in fetchedcoins:
        coinid = coins[1]
        coinname = coins[0]
    
        var = StringVar()
        c = Checkbutton(selectframe, text=coinname, variable=var,onvalue=coinid,offvalue='false')
        c.deselect() 
        c.pack()


def pastedids():
    coinids = Label(selectframe,text=var.get())
    coinids.pack()
showidbtn = Button(selectframe,text='show IDs',command=pastedids)
showidbtn.pack()
```

Comment: Is the last five lines within the function `selectcoins()`? Since you used same variable `var` for all the `Checkbutton` widgets in the for loop, so it only reflects the state of the last checkbutton.

Comment: What do you want to show when more than one checkbutton are selected?

Comment: @acw the last five lines are not withing the `selectcoins` function. yeah im aware of how it reflects the state of the last button, but im mainly just looking for a way to create the checkbuttons using the for loop without having the last button be reflected in the variable. when more than one checkbutton is selected, id like for it to return a list or tuple of the multiple selected records.

Comment: If the last five lines are not within `selectcoins()`, then `selectframe` is undefined inside `pastedids()`.

Comment: You can use a list to store the `StringVar`s for each checkbuttons.